# Alamofire multipart form data request not working for 'EDGE' type network?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlconnection, alamofire, multipartform-data

I am in the process of developing one iPhone application. I am uploading image / video to the server **via multipart**. Whenever i am on **3G/LTE/wifi network** ,it works smoothly . But when i am on **EDGE network**, it gives error message from server. Further we managed to get server logs, From that we get to know that parameters for the request are not reaching to server when i try via **EDGE network** so that server omits error.

Here is Alamofire session manager code

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 500
        manager.session.configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true




       manager.upload(multipartFormData: {..})
```

Note : I have also tried without setting configuration for sessionmanager (directly used Alamofire.request )
Let me know if you have any idea to solve this.